# Cannot change color of Eclipse editor tabs

Tags: eclipse, themes

I tried to configure the color for my editor tabs (see image below)

[image]

According to this, my active tab should look like the tab "ipsum".

But even after applying these settings, I have the following situation(ExtractWordCounts is the active tab)

[image]

Can anyone suggest some solution?

Comment: I wasted 1 hour on fixing this but not done. Eclipse is not user friendly. I hope someone will bring out a better IDE to replace this clumsy monster.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A bit late, but I clicked/pressed the wrong button and the tab color changed, and the color was just not readable, after playing around with

`window -> preferences -> general -> appearance -> Colors and Fonts`

If you type in the search bar **focus** you will see the options to change the tab color:
[image]

### Additional!

I **recommend** using [DevStyle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle) Theme, it is just awesome!

Comment: A bit tricky with all those options available when you don't even have an idea which one is the one that you want to change. But the default white foreground on white background is really annoying, better change anything in sight to some non-white color and figure out later what is what. Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: The strategy I use is to guess as to which settings might be the one you want and set each of those to a wildly different color, then restart Eclipse and see if any of them made the difference you wanted. You can then use the colors to find the element you really wanted and change it to what you really wanted, then reset the others. This is just one more annoyance of Eclipse that could be easily resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Refer these.

1. Use eclipse [color theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org)
2. Jeeeyl [theme](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes)
3. Switch your themes in `Window > Preferences > General > Appearance`

Also check this [blog post](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/11/dark-eclipse-ships-with-eclipse-luna/)