# How do I change the main color of Eclipse RSA window?

Tags: eclipse, colors, rational-rsa

I must work with two workspaces and often the files contained into these two workspaces are the same.

I need distinguishing a workspace immediatly, for reduce the probability of working into the wrong workspace. So I would like changing the main color of the Eclipse (RSA) window (red lines in screenshot), but I was be able to change only the color of tabs (blue circles in screenshot).

Someone knows how could I change the color of the main window?

Thanks

[image: RSA screenshot]

Comment: You can put the workspace name in the title bar - Preferences > General > Workspace 'Workspace name'

Comment: Yes, but I want to see the difference between the two workspaces immediately, having only a look at the window, without searching with eyes at the top-left corner and reading the workspace name.

Comment: Check this answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841415/cannot-change-color-of-eclipse-editor-tabs/22853819#22853819.

Jeeeyl Plugin helpful for you.